# Why my service closes when I close the application?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm doing a send an image to the server using the Volley class, as the process and a bit time consuming ressolvi do for a service in the background, then I start the service by sending some parameters by intent.

**Starting Service**

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadImagesBackground.class).putExtra("bitmap", filePath.toString()));
```

**Service**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {


    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(); - iniciando o comando");
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand(); - generateID: " + startId);


    // GET STRING IMAGE
    if (intent != null){
        extra = intent.getExtras();
        image = getStringImage(extra.getString("bitmap"));
        //Salvar no bundle
        new SharedPreferencesUtil(UploadImagesBackground.this).saveImagesToUpload(image);

        prepareUpload(startId,image);
    }else{
        Log.v(TAG, "A INTENT FOI NULA");
        if (image != null){
            Log.v(TAG, "IMAGE NAO FOI NULA");
            prepareUpload(startId,image);
        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "IMAGE FOI NULA");
            displayNotification(startId, 3, "Por favor nao feche o aplicativo", 100);
        }

    }



    //return START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And for debug:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v(TAG, "//--------------------------");
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate(); - Serviço criado com sucesso");

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy(); - Servico destruido com sucesso");
    Log.v(TAG, "--------------------------//");
}
```

Service is performed without error, the more the problem I'm going and that when the User closes the application for the "Application drawer" (Recents apps) my service is canceled and re-created, which causes me the image incomplete submission

[image: "Application drawer" (Recents app)]

What did you think strange that the User only exit the application using the back, and not close the drawer the service continues to run in the peaceful plan without being recreated.
In some research, I found some recommendations to use `android:stopWithTask= "false"` however did not work
In some research, I found some recommendations to use stop With Task = false however did not work, I even tried to make my available service to the system using `android:exported="true"`, however nothing solved my problem, the statement of my service in `AndroidManifest`:

```
    <service
        android:name=".ServicosBackground.UploadImagesBackground"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
```

Please, help me!

Comment: did you write service related code in onDestroy or onStop method?. if did mention the code in this thread.

Comment: I just used Log to debug: `Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy(); - Servico destruido com sucesso");`